# Logstash transform data by calling API

Tags: api, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

I'm new to logstash and was wondering if it is possible to transform data by calling an http API.

What I exactly want to achieve is translating the id's from our branches to geolocations, to be able to visualize the data in kibana on a map.

Can somebody help me with how to do this, or point me in the right direction.

Comment: "id's" or "IPs"? There's already a plugin to revolve IP addresses to locations.

Comment: I have an API that resolves my custom ID that are being logged, to geo location data, so IP resolving will not help me

Comment: There is a filter plugin which does exactly this. [Logstash-filter-rest](https://github.com/lucashenning/logstash-filter-rest) You might use it to send a field of your choice to your API (via http post) and save the result in a new field. Let me know if you need some help with the configuration.